# Difference between Extract method and Extract local function in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

In visual studio, if you select some part of code and press **Ctrl + .** then it shows following options (see screenshot)

1. Extract Method
2. Extract Local Function

What is the difference between the two?[image]

Comment: One would be a "standard" method and one a local function. Local function are function within other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is detail explanation -
In Visual Studio, both "Extract Method" and "Extract Local Function" are refactoring techniques that help improve code organization, readability, and maintainability. However, they are used in slightly different scenarios.

Extract Method:
This refactoring technique involves taking a portion of code within a method and moving it to a new method. This is useful when you have a block of code that performs a specific task or has a clear purpose within the original method. By extracting this code into a separate method, you can give it a meaningful name, make the original method more focused, and promote code reuse.

Example:
Let's say you have a long method that performs some calculations, validation, and data manipulation. You can identify a specific portion of this method that handles data validation. By extracting that part into a separate method, you make the code more modular and readable.

Extract Local Function:
This refactoring technique involves defining a new function within the scope of an existing function. Local functions are only accessible within the containing function. They are useful when you have a small piece of logic that aids the main function's readability or performs a specific sub-task within that function.

Example:
Imagine you have a complex calculation method that involves several steps and sub-calculations. Instead of having long and nested code blocks, you can define local functions for each sub-calculation. This keeps the main method focused on the high-level logic while breaking down the details into local functions.